# Converting multi-dimensional array to a tuple in python

Tags: python, arrays, stdtuple

I am getting some frame data from a web cam in the form of rgb values.

```
import numpy as np    
frame = get_video()
print np.shape(frame)
```

The output is (480, 640, 3). Now I want to construct image from these values. So, I want to use

```
im = Image.new("RGB", (480, 640),frame)
```

But, here the third argument takes a tuple. I get this error

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

So, my question is what is the best way to convert this frame data to a tuple, so that I can construct my image.

Comment: What does get_video() give?

Comment: get_video() gets the RGB values of the video frame. So basically frame contains 480x640 RGB values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this implementation to be faster

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new("RGB", (480, 640), (0, 0, 0) ) #initialize 480:640 black image
while True:
 frame = get_video()
 im = Image.fromarray(frame)
 im.save('some-name', 'JPEG')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you are importing the class Image from PIL.

The documentation for Image.new(), accessed with console command Image.new? is:

In [3]: Image.new?

Type:       function

Base Class: 

String Form:

Namespace:  Interactive

File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py

Definition: Image.new(mode, size, color=0)

Docstring:  Create a new image

The third parameter is an RGB color, such as (255,255,255), to fill the hole image. You can't initialize individual pixels with this function.

I am also assuming that frame is a 3D array. As your output suggests, it's 480 lines and 640 rows of RGB tuples.

I don't know if there is a simpler way to do this, but I would set the pixel values by the putpixel() function, something like:

```
im = Image.new( "RGB", (480, 640), (0, 0, 0) ) #initialize 480:640 black image
for i in range(480):
    for j in range(640):
        im.putpixel( (i, j), tuple(frame[i][j]) )
```

Always check the docstring via console, it saves a lot of time. I also recommend using ipython as your console.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer if you replace `im.putpixel( (i, j), frame[i][j] )` with `im.putpixel( (i, j), tuple(frame[i][j]) )`. It works well, but I am actually trying to live stream this video and it works very slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Done. It could be a better way, I've never actually used PIL.